# How do you apply an scss template to vuetify?

Tags: sass, vuetify.js, vue-cli

Vuetify seems to define it's default dark theme [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_dark.scss), and I would like to overwrite some of those values with custom colors.

It seems like scss is the way to overwrite this. However, when I try to change the backgound color, I don't see any change.

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/main.sass';

$material-dark: () !default;
$material-dark: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'background': #FFFF00
  ),
  $material-dark
);
```

I'm importing it in main.js (`import "./example.scss"`), and I know it's loading (syntax errors make it crash), but the dark themed background doesn't change. If this isn't how vuetify styling works, what is?

Answer (score 0):

For vue-cli, the scss style must be included in vue.config.js, ie.

```
module.exports = {
  "configureWebpack": {
  },
  "css": {
    "loaderOptions": {
      "sass": {
        "prependData": `@import "~@/styles/main.scss"` // change the route with you main.scss location in yout proyect
      }
    }
  },
  "lintOnSave": false,
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  "publicPath": ".",
}
```

Also, the scss file should import styles.sass instead of main.sass. ie.

`@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';`